# Consulta en mysql. con registros multiples

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

nesesito ayuda con la siguiente consulta, nesesito que esta consulta me devuelva el estado ID el nombre del estado y la sumatoria del total del capital activo en cada uno de estos.

la consulta que genere es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT  est.EstadoID,est.Nombre,sum(min.Capital)
FROM MINISTRACREDAGRO min 
inner join DIRECCLIENTE dir on dir.ClienteID
inner join ESTADOSREPUB est on est.EstadoID=dir.EstadoID
where min.FechaPagoMinis>='2021-01-01' and min.FechaPagoMinis<='2021-12-31'
```

la cual me genera los siguientes resultados:

```
1   AGUASCALIENTES  840460.00
1   AGUASCALIENTES  353168.00
1   AGUASCALIENTES  563190.00
4   CAMPECHE    45585.00
4   CAMPECHE    982.00
4   CAMPECHE    175000.00
4   CAMPECHE    2665.00
4   CAMPECHE    2000000.00
4   CAMPECHE    4000000.00
4   CAMPECHE    700000.00
```

Hasta aquí todo normal, pero a la hora de poner un sum(capital) en el select me devuelve una sola fina con el primer estado y con la sumatoria de todos los estados.

```
EstadoID    Nombre  sum(min.Capital)
1   AGUASCALIENTES  6125728015208.76
```

lo que quiero que me devuelva es algo similar a esto:

```
EstadoID    Nombre  sum(min.Capital)
1   AGUASCALIENTES  6125728015208.76
2   MICHOACÁN       8798778784.90
3   JALISCO         987787.SUM
```

Si alguien me pudiera orientar

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema? tenes que hacer un group by... si no, solo suma todo...

Comment: Es muy probable que tengas que usar un `GROUP BY`, pero sin ver un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable de los datos poco podremos ayudarte. Considera agregar un fiddle que incluya la creación de las tablas y unos pocos INSERT para poder ver el problema. Aparte del `GROUP BY` puede que no arroje los datos esperados porque algunos criterios no se cumplen, para eso hay que ver la realidad de los datos.

Comment: concuerdo, con el group by es muy posibles que te funcione

Comment: gracias a todos, si efectivamente es con un group by